# does expo:build look at git or file state?

Tags: android, ios, git, build, expo

I'm having trouble understanding how `expo build:android` and `expo build:ios` work exactly. Do they reference your last git commit on the current branch when creating the build, or do they look at your current file state? I couldn't find anything in their documentation about this.

It would seem that in order for changes to be in effect in my next expo build, I must first make a commit to git, rather than just save my project. Was the expo build tool designed to work like this, or am I doing something unusual?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.